# Как сделать так, чтобы балуны отображались рядом без накладки друг на друга?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Как можно настроить, чтобы балуны, которые близко друг к другу не перекрывали друг друга, а отображались рядышком?

[Пример, как я хочу реализовать](https://maps.yandex.ua/?text=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F%2C%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE-%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BD%2C%20%D0%90%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C%203&l=map&sll=37.067831%2C55.543726&sspn=0.334396%2C0.088669&ll=36.367709%2C55.584373&z=9&ol=geo&oll=37.078817%2C55.545752&whatshere%5Bpoint%5D=37.074955%2C55.540612&whatshere%5Bzoom%5D=13)

И вот, как реализовано у меня: http://www.reformauto.ru/auxpage_sto_map

Comment: Возможно, я что-то не так делаю, но в приведенном вами примере на яндексе балуны перекрывают друг друга.

Answer (score 1):

Объедините все метки в один массив и используйте объект [Clusterer](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ClusterPlacemark-docpage/) из API Yandex Карт (все метки отобразятся как одна большая, а при увеличении масштаба каждая будет отдельно). [Подробный пример](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/geoobjects-docpage/#clusters).

Comment: не это не вариант, я не могу кого-либо ущемлять и прятать по одну большую точку. нужно отображать каждую точку как самостоятельную.